# org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not registered : org/"Xx<XaXaXXaXaX>xX/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, xss

So basically, JSF is trying to render one link to the `ajax4jsf` CSS file that has "`Xx< XaXaXXaXaX>xX` as part of it.
This raises an exception right away of course.

The point is how is this even there:

```
org/"Xx< XaXaXXaXaX>xX/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss
```

when what it should be is this
 `org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss`. Is there any possibility that we had some kind of XSS attack that has lead us to this? "`Xx< XaXaXXaXaX>xX` seems to be a pretty popular string when it comes to get into a system...

Does anyone how to solve this?

**EDIT**

Inside the richfaces-ui jar I've found this file: 
richfaces-ui-3.3.1.GA\META-INF\resources-config.xml

This has this resource:

```
< name >org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss< /name >

< path >org/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss< /path >
```

But it seems that somehow it's not being got properly since I got this error afterwards:

```
2013-09-25 19:48:02,297 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/].[Faces Servlet]] (http-10.60.67.140-8443-6) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource not registered : org/"Xx<XaXaXXaXaX>xX/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResource(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:406)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.ResourceBuilderImpl.getResourceForKey(ResourceBuilderImpl.java:350)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:152)
    at org.ajax4jsf.resource.InternetResourceService.serviceResource(InternetResourceService.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:905)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:592)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:2036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As a note aside, this only happens on production. I've read that JSF 1.2 is vulnerable to XSS attacks, so after seeing that "`Xx< XaXaXXaXaX>xX` is the problem here, that would mean that that could be injected somehow...

Comment: Is this caused by code you wrote?

Comment: Not really, this is automatically generated by richfaces. I'm adding more information to the post

Comment: How does the generated HTML output really look like?

Comment: I couldn't tell because Richfaces raises the exception before generating anything, but if it didn't failed it should be something like <link href="org/"Xx<XaXaXXaXaX>xX/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss" />. Anyway, I'm changing the ResourceBuilderImpl class myself so I can bypass or patch this error. Once I got this done I will post the result for those who are interested.

Comment: You didn't understood my comment. However, your answer has already confirmed this: the generated HTML output doesn't contain those URLs. By the way, use `@nickname` to notify others about a comment-reply if there are more than 2 users participating in comments. I didn't see your comment-reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that a bot or something of the sort was trying to access to that kind of files modifying slightly the URLs of the resources. 
Our decision so far is to restrain all the wrong request through the web.xml.

As a note aside, we are thinking that this could be an attacker trying to figure out the resource locations of our system.

Comment: In other words, JSF/RichFaces didn't generate HTML with those URLs and thus it's not their fault, on the contrary to what you're implying in the question.

Comment: Was one of the possible causes. And I didn't say that Richfaces generates the html nor it was a Richfaces bug: Richfaces generates the exception when it doesn't find the resource. After looking at the code, Richfaces can get this resources from the resources-config.xml, so I thought that could be change in my server with another config file enabling someone to inject the wrong URI. The other and most likely is that someone is trying to access to that resource by URL and then Richfaces raise the exception. As I said, we are adding a constraint to avoid this. Hope this make everything more clear

Comment: You literally said: *"JSF is trying to render one link to the ajax4jsf CSS file that has "Xx< XaXaXXaXaX>xX as part of it."* In other words, you said that the link appeared a such in the generated HTML output. If that isn't what you intented, then perhaps you misunderstood the actual meaning of the term "render".

Comment: Is trying to render, which is not the same. A part of the render process is finding the resource, which is what raises the exception. So, if this was the case, no successful render is carried out (no html is being generated cause this redirects to a error page, ok?). Anyway, this exception can be trigger also by the manual access to this resource, which after looking at the Richfaces source is more likely to be happening.

Comment: And by the way, I don't mind get downvotes but I prefer to know the reason why. I was wondering which was the problem with this error and tried to explain myself the best I could, so if any of the users is still there I'd appreciate the reason why? Thanks.

Comment: @PainyJames Probably if you reformulated "JSF is trying to render link" to something like: "According to whatever logs something/someone is accessing the specified url which causes the following exception" you would get some upvotes.